# Passing data to controller in ASP.NET MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

What am I doing wrong?

I want to pass `Id` to the controller where I can use it.

My controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ListCoach(int id)
{
    List<Training> ListCoachTraining = _TraningService.ListCoach(id);
    var ChoachList = _TraningService.Coach(id);
    return View(ChoachList);
}
```

My view - what is correct way call the script? It doesn't work right now:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="~/Content/no_foto.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">@item.Name</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <div id="textButton">
                                <a href="~/TrainingType/ListCoach" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Go to anywhere</a>
                                <a id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Go to anywhere</a>
                                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save" />
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                }
        </div>
    </div>
//call the script
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/ManagerAccount.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My script - I use Ajax for it. There I want to pass `id` to the controller:

```
function PassToContoller(data) {
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: '/TrainingType/ListCoach',
            data: { id: data },
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = '/appUser/ManageAccount';
                //return data;
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#loader").fadeOut("slow");
                console.log("error1");
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: How are you routing to the  ListCoach method? did you define proper routing?
  $.ajax(: type:"GET", (get is capital not sure if it makes a difference)

Comment: Would you kindly share your `Training` class defination. So that it can be reporduce accordingly.

Comment: yes exectly it was mistake I edit rout but it dosent work  correct route: url: '/TrainingType/ListCoach',

Comment: Please have a try the solution on `Update with Comment  Can I do without?` part which has the solution of your last comment. Every way has been shown now it's your choice which one you would implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't call the `function` accordingly. You are expecting your `PassToContoller` function should invoke while you click on `save` in your case either you have to call this function with `btnSave` `onlick` or `onClick="PassToContoller(@item.Name)"`

I am showing you both here:

***When `onClick="PassToContoller(@item.Name)"` In Line:***

***`Razor HTML`***

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    @*<img src="~/Content/no_foto.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">*@
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">@item.Name</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <div id="textButton">
                            <a href="~/TrainingType/ListCoach" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Go to anywhere</a>
                            <a id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Go to anywhere</a>
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnSave" onClick="PassToContoller(@item.Name)" value="Save"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

***Script:***

```
<script>
    function PassToContoller(data) {
        alert(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/ListCoachController/ListCoach',
            data: { id: data },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                window.location.href = '/appUser/ManageAccount';
                return data;
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#loader").fadeOut("slow");
                console.log("error1");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Aother way btnSave Onlick:***

> In this you need few modifications:
>
> Need to introduce a input type text which will be hidden it will
> contrain a value like this `<input type="text" id="getValue" value="@item.Name" hidden />` and will pass that hidden value when you
> would click the button.

Another thing is your `btnSave` seems you have used same for other button as well so your `onclick` function will getConfused which event to fired. So need to set `unique btn id` Now rest of the same like below:

***`Razor HTML`***

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    @*<img src="~/Content/no_foto.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">*@
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">@item.Name</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <div id="textButton">
                            <a href="~/TrainingType/ListCoach" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Go to anywhere</a>
                            <a id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Go to anywhere</a>
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnNewSave" value="Save" />
                            <input type="text" id="getValue" value="@item.Name" hidden />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

***Script:***

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnNewSave").click(function () {
                var data = $("#getValue").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '/ListCoachController/AnotherListCoach',
                    data: { id: data },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        window.location.href = '/appUser/ManageAccount';
                        return data;
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $("#loader").fadeOut("slow");
                        console.log("error1");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

***Update:***
Based on your new requirement on comment you just need to update your `HTML` like below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    @*<img src="~/Content/no_foto.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">*@
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">@item.Name</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <div id="textButton">
                            <a href="~/TrainingType/ListCoach"  class="btn btn-primary" onClick="PassToContoller(@item.Name)">Go to anywhere</a>
                            <a  class="btn btn-primary" onClick="PassToContoller(@item.Name)">Go to anywhere</a>
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick="PassToContoller(@item.Name)" value="Save" />
                            <input type="text" id="getValue" value="@item.Name" hidden />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

> ***Note:*** You have to get rid of `id="btnSave"` from all the `<a>` and `<button>` and need to replace with
> `onClick="PassToContoller(@item.Name)"` it will pass all of your
> value. No matter how many cycle you have.

***Update with Comment  `Can I do without?`:***

***HTML:***

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    @*<img src="~/Content/no_foto.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">*@
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">@item.Name</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <div id="textButton">
                            <a href="#"  class="btn btn-primary" >Go to anywhere</a>
                            <a  class="btn btn-primary">Go to anywhere</a>
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  value="Save" />
                            <input type="text" id="getValue" value="@item.Name" hidden />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

***Script:***

```
 @section scripts {
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function PassToContoller(data) {
                alert(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '/UserLog/AnotherListCoach',
                    data: { id: data },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        window.location.href = '/appUser/ManageAccount';
                        return data;
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $("#loader").fadeOut("slow");
                        console.log("error1");
                    }
                });
            }
            $(document).ready(function () {
               
                $("a").click(function () {
                    var data = $("#getValue").val();
                    var callFunc = PassToContoller(data)
                });
                $(":button").click(function () {
                    var data = $("#getValue").val();
                    var callFunc = PassToContoller(data)
                });
                
            });
        </script>
    }
```

Hope it would guide you accordingly. You can used either of the approach.

Comment: Thank you sir it worked. But I dont get it. I have cycle For where I get six or ten value ` <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnNewSave" value="Save" />` this's won't work if I choose second or third card

Comment: Which approach you are adapting? I  have seen you had on item only which is `@item.Name`?

Comment: Did you mean whichever button been clicked you want to call the same function is it?

Comment: Yes, I would like to do it. is it posible?

Comment: Yes possible in that need to set your button id dynamically which is diffrent issue, but here your main question were how to invoke that function I mostly focus on that.

Comment: I would like dont use onClick in html I heard it's bad practice. Can I do without?

Comment: Please have a try the solution on `Update with Comment  Can I do without?` part which has the solution of your last comment. Every way has been shown now it's your choice which one you would implement.

Comment: Briliant. Thank you sir. For next to problem I will make new topic. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

With `GET` method, you should pass the data via query string
`/TrainingType/ListCoach?id=1`

In ASP.NET MVC, we have default route template is `{Controller}/{Action}/{id}`
So, alternative we can use this URL
`/TrainingType/ListCoach/1`

Comment: if I change GEt to POST. can I use Jquery for passing data to controller?

Comment: You can use either of it, I am showing you the way.

Comment: @Boris: Could you check the value of `data`? If it contains non-digit characters, the `id` in action unable to binding because its data type is `int`.